# Java - Pulling From Database With Prepared Statement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I'm having a problem returning a single record from my database.
Every time I run the code it returns null.
The code fails on the asterisked line below.
My code is:

```
 public Map<String,Object> retrieveRecordById(String tableName, 
        String column, int primaryKey) 
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Map<String,Object> record = null;
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + column + "=?";

        try{
            openDatabaseConnection();
            pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pStmt.setObject(1, primaryKey);
   *********** pStmt.executeQuery(query); ***********
            rs = pStmt.executeQuery(query);
            metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int colCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

            if(rs.next()) {
                record = new HashMap<>();
                for(int i=1; i < colCount; i++) {
                    record.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
                }
            }

        } catch(IllegalArgumentException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }finally{
            pStmt.close();
            closeDatabaseConnection();
        }

    return record;
}
```

And the output from the console is:
*null*

And the error message is:
*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1*

Comment: And reason for failing? any exception stack?

Comment: Why the question mark in "=?" ?

Comment: @APH that's a parametized query APH

Comment: @Nambari error message is 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"

Comment: inst it because you are setting the query to  "Where column  ='primaryKey'" once pStmt.setObject(1, primaryKey); is done.Column have name; not id.

Comment: When using a prepared statement you should use the no parameter executeQuery method `pStmt.executeQuery();`

Comment: 1) That is not full stack trace, do printstacktrace. 2) Print your query using System.out.print... that should give you clue on what's wrong.

Comment: @Asura The problem is it's not setting the object to the integer I'm passing in. Your last two sentence fragments lost me. Clarify?

Comment: @BevynQ You were right! Thanks for your help! If you would like to add the answer I would be happy to approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `executeQuery(String)` instead of just `executeQuery()` without parameters. This actually make the prepared statement behave like a regular `Statement`, passing the original string - with the question mark still in it - to the server.

A prepared statement already contains the query string. Just run its `executeQuery()` without a parameter and it will use the one inside it, replacing the question mark with the value you gave it.